# Hough transform: Where to place negative rhos in accumulator matrix

Tags: algorithm, hough-transform

I'm trying to implement [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) algorithm.

I set the origin of [cartesian plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) in upper left corner of the image.

The range of theta (angle between rho and X axis) is *1..180*, with a step of *1* degree. The maximum size of *rho* is the size of diagonal of the image. 
I want to calculate the accumulator matrix. Given the information above its size should be *Y*: rho, *X*: 180 (*theta*).

The algorithm seems simple to me, but there is a problem with *rho*. There will be negative values for it. For theta from *0* to *PI/2* rho will be only positive, because *sin* and *cos* are positive. Yet for theta from *PI/2* to *PI*, because *cos* is negative here, while *sin* positive, depending on x, y coordinates of the point, rho might have negative values.

My question is: how should I deal with the negative values of *rho* when calculating the accumulator matrix? Where should I place them?

Answer (score 0):

In rho-theta space lines `L1 = (rho, theta)` and `L2 = (rho, theta + 180)`  are the same, because line has no selected direction.

So just change negative `theta` (how did you get it?) to `theta + 180`

Comment: So I suppose I have to switch to (theta + 180) whenever r is negative for (theta), and vice-versa. Is this right? I took an example, for theta = 2PI/3, and (x,y) = (9,4). 'r' is negative in this case (-1.03). But for theta = PI + 2PI/3 it's positive (1.03).

Comment: You should not get negative values at all. For every non-zero point you increment all suitable cells in array with index range 0..179 (or 1..180) and 0..diagonal